# Search SSMS Agent Jobs for a Table Name

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Is there a way to search the SQL Server agent jobs, at the same time with a SQL query, for a specific table name?

Something like this:

```
Select top 100 *
from job_1
where definition like '%table_1%'
```

but instead of 1 job, it's all of the jobs?

Comment: That would depend on how you build and execute your job steps. Do you use t-sql directly in each job step? You might want to give a little more detail about your expected results - do you only want to know if the sql you are searching for is in a job, or other details?

Comment: Just wanted to search the jobs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Agent jobs are stored in the `msdb` database.

If I understand your intention, this should give you a start:

```
select j.name JobName, s.step_name StepName
from msdb.dbo.sysjobsteps s
join msdb.dbo.sysjobs j on j.job_id=s.job_id
where s.command like '%findme%'
```